Unable to run VisualGDB Unit Tests from Azure DevOps CI
Azure DevOps Question!!!
Hi,
I'm trying to run Unit Tests from Azure DevOps using [VisualGDB + JLink debugger] on a remote target. Running unit tests from agent server's command line work successfully and I got a compiled report for unit tests.
But from CI the Unit Tests task just stuck and timeout, here you can see; Moreover, while this task is stuck the required process[VisualGDB + JLinkGDBremoteCLI.exe] got created on agent server but they don't work ... Here's the script I'm using to run unit tests
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Run Unit Tests'
  timeoutInMinutes: 3
  continueOnError: true
  inputs:
    targetType: inline
    script: |
      cd $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/source/${{parameters.sourceDir}}
      VisualGDB.exe /runtests ${{parameters.sourceDir}}.vgdbcmake /platform:Hardware /config:RelWithDebInfo /targetPath:$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)\unittest /vsoutput:${{parameters.sourceDir}}-unit-test-report.trx
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=timedOut]false"

Thanks,
Umair
The Unit Tests should run from Azure DevOps CI pipeline as they are running from agent server commandline ...

can you try `jobs:

job: Test
timeoutInMinutes: 10 # how long to run the job before automatically cancelling
cancelTimeoutInMinutes: 2 # how much time to give 'run always even if cancelled tasks' before stopping them`/
timeoutInMinutes: 0 should also work for individual tasks, and 0 means max value (infinite for self-hosted agents).

**timeoutInMinutes : **  Time to wait for this job to complete before the server kills it.
cancelTimeoutInMinutes : Time to wait for the job to cancel before forcibly terminating it.

try with timeoutInMinutes: 0
